# Remove image url from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

replacing image using JavaScript

I want to remove **oldSrc** from DOM after url replace

```
var oldSrc = 'www.domain.com/spinner.gif';
var newSrc = 'cdn.domain.com/spinner.gif';
$('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', newSrc);
```

Comment: no need to remove , just replace `src` so old one will remove automatic.

Comment: Your URLs are the same. (And they need a protocol, right now they're relative to the page.)

Comment: Maybe you can do it with getting that element and modifying its `src` variable

Comment: @DominikMatis - The above does that, via jQuery's `attr`. (It sets the attribute, which means the change is visible via the reflected property as well.)

Comment: Aside from the broken URLs and repeated image in both old and new src, the code should work for you. Do you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i tried but old image is present in DOM content

Comment: @uDAY - Not with the code above, assuming `oldUrl` is really **exactly** what you have in `src` in the `img` element. (You're not using "View Source", right? Because that's always what was delivered from the server. Use the DOM or Elements tab in your browser's dev tools.)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', newSrc);
```

**modifies** the existing `img` element(s) with the old `src`. So there's no need to do anything more, those elements will now show the image from the new `src`.

Example: After a brief pause, this replaces my avatar with yours:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var oldSrc = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG";
    var newSrc = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/85c1241443e5568a57754958d30beff4?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
    $('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', newSrc);
}, 800);
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank for reply but image is not remove DOM content.

Comment: @uDAY - I don't know what you mean by "DOM content" in that sentence. It doesn't remove the `img` element, no, but if you want to remove the `img` element, there's no point in changing its `src` first. You seem to have missed [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393167/remove-image-url-from-dom/57393232?noredirect=1#comment101268598_57393167) earlier.

Comment: @uDAY - It doesn't make any sense to look for DOM content in the Network tab. As I said in that comment, you look in the DOM or Elements tab.

Comment: i m getting this error **Serve resources from a consistent URL**  on gtmetrix